# How to embedd a youtube video inside a swf

Tags: flash, youtube, embed

Embedding YouTube videos using the embed code in a blog or HTML/PHP page is straight forward.

Is there a simple method to "embed" the same video within a Flash/swf interface?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try loading it with `Loader` class? I guess YouTube's crossdomain would allow it to be loaded from anywhere.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(loader);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/v/CrypticVideoID"));
```

Comment: I'm a bit behind and only have Flash 8... so can't try the loader class but have tried loadMovie()

Comment: This page says loadMovie works http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=122501&page=9